# curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection inside all docker container of VM host

Tags: docker, ssl, curl, openssl, boot2docker

I created ubuntu 16.04 VM (virtualBox) and install docker-ce (18.03.0) then
I created some container with curl, try curl https://google.com inside all container was found error:

```
root@7ca161fc6292:/# curl -sSL https://google.com
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to google.com:443
```

Ping 8.8.8.8, google.com inside all container is ok!
How can I fix it?

Comment: `curl -sSL https://google.com` is ok on VM host

Comment: What container are you running? Can you share your Dockerfile / image?

Comment: @codemonkey I used ubuntu image with install curl and jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion and byrnedo/alpine-curl...

Comment: It's not clear to me in which container you are getting this error. You have listed 3 images: 1) ubuntu (16.04?), 2) jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion and 3) byrnedo/alpine-curl. I have tried running the curl command above with all 3 images without any errors. Can you provide more details of exactly how to reproduce this error?

Comment: I mean I got this error on all container above, My VM host has 2 network interface( bride and nat).

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of running the command with the verbose (-v) flag? i.e. `curl -sSL https://google.com -v`